# volume of solid generated by the regin bounded by curve $y=\sqrt{x},y=\frac{x-3}{2},y=0$ about $x$ axis

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

> Using sell method to find the volume of solid generated by revolving the region bounded by $$y=\sqrt{x},y=\frac{x-3}{2},y=0$$ about $x$ axis, is (using shell method)

What I try:

[image]

Solving two given curves $$\sqrt{x}=\frac{x-3}{2}\Longrightarrow x^2-10x+9=0$$

We have $x=1$ (Invalid) and $x=9$ (Valid).

Put $x=9$ in $y=\sqrt{x}$ we have $y=3$

Now Volume of solid form by rotation about $x$ axis is

$$=\int^{9}_{0}2\pi y\bigg(y^2-2y-3\bigg)dy$$

Is my Volume Integral is right? If not then how do I solve it? Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would instead split this up into two integrals:

$$\pi\int_0^3{(\sqrt{x})^2}dx + \pi\int_3^9{(\sqrt{x})^2-\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^2}dx$$.

Using the shell method:

$$\int_0^3{2\pi y(2y+3-y^2)}dy$$.

Comment: Thanks justaguy can you plesse tell me using Shell method.

Comment: This i believe is the shell method if I am not wrong

Comment: No this,is Disk method

Comment: alright I will do the other way.

Comment: I edited my answer, you just have the signs reversed, hope this helps. Please ask questions if you have any :)

Comment: Thanks justaguy. But this value is negative.

Comment: Sorry I think our bounds are wrong, we should be doing from 0 to 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109228/discussion-between-justaguy-and-jacky).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Divide the region bounded by the curves $y_1=\sqrt x$ & $y_2=\frac{x-3}{2}$ from $x=0$ to $x=9$ into two parts. One part is bounded by the curve $y_1=\sqrt x$ from $x=0$ to $x=9$ & revolved around x-axis. Other part is bounded by the curve $y_2=\frac{x-3}{2}$ from $x=3$ to $x=9$ & revolved around x-axis

The required volume of bounded region revolved around x-axis is given as
$$\int_0^{9}\pi y_1^2dx-\int_{3}^{9} \pi y_2^2\ dx$$
$$=\int_0^{9}\pi (\sqrt x)^2dx-\int_{3}^{9} \pi \left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^2\ dx$$

Comment: Thanks Harish Chandra. Can you please tell me using Shell method.